# AWS Lambda FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When running my Lambda function which processes a file, I’m getting the following error

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

The file is a 1GB file. I have allocated 10GB max mem sizes to my Lambda. I’m running Nodejs v16.

````
<--- Last few GCs --->  
[10:0x557d6727a030] 448851 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 9214.0 (9362.4) -> 9212.9 (9362.4) MB, 5730.0 / 0.0 ms (average mu = 0.071, current mu = 0.011) allocationfailure scavenge might not succeed  
[10:0x557d6727a030] 454575 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 9214.2 (9362.7) -> 9213.1 (9362.7) MB, 5720.8 / 0.0 ms (average mu = 0.036, current mu = 0.001) allocationfailure scavenge might not succeed  
<--- JS stacktrace --->  
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory  
1: 0x557d61d87373 node::Abort() [/var/lang/bin/node]  
2: 0x557d61c62d10 [/var/lang/bin/node]  
3: 0x557d61fa171d v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/var/lang/bin/node]  
4: 0x557d61fa1a1e v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/var/lang/bin/node]  
5: 0x557d621b0c58 [/var/lang/bin/node]  
6: 0x557d621b1b90 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [/var/lang/bin/node]  
7: 0x557d621c2439 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/var/lang/bin/node]  
8: 0x557d621c2f69 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/var/lang/bin/node]  
9: 0x557d621c6a2b v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/var/lang/bin/node]  
10: 0x557d62178c39 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/var/lang/bin/node]  
11: 0x557d6259971e v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/var/lang/bin/node]  
12: 0x557d62a23939 [/var/lang/bin/node]  
RequestId: 402a144a-c120-4471-a6ed-76b0592edeccError: Runtime exited with error: signal: aborted Runtime.ExitError  
END RequestId: 402a144a-c120-4471-a6ed-76b0592edecc  
REPORT RequestId: 402a144a-c120-4471-a6ed-76b0592edecc Duration: 679666.28 ms Billed Duration: 679667 ms Memory Size: 10240 MB Max Memory Used: 10240 MB Init Duration: 441.19 ms  XRAY TraceId: 1-64d4f617-3be82fb173bd513a7b593c5d SegmentId: 3637e1c406b00ecf Sampled: true```
````

Comment: Just because the file is 1gb does not mean processing doesn't require more than 10 gb.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by fixing the way the Lambda processed the file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).